# Android/Firebase Calculating the sum of numeric rows in same child

Tags: android, firebase

I have Database like this:

```
"Users" : {
  "user_ykdF5b234afdgd" : {
        "Scoring" : [ {
          "Name" : "Name1",
          "punkte" : "0"
        }, {
          "Name" : "Name2",
          "punkte" : "0"
        } ],
        "image" : "",
        "membertype" : "bike",
        "startnummer" : "1",
        "teamname" : "Paul Musterman"
      }
    },
    "user_ykdF5b234afdgd2" : {
        "Scoring" : [ {
          "Name" : "Name1",
          "punkte" : "0"
        }, {
          "Name" : "Name2",
          "punkte" : "0"
        } ],
        "image" : "",
        "membertype" : "bike",
        "startnummer" : "1",
        "teamname" : "Franz Musterman"
      }
    },
```

user_ykdF5b234afdgd is in my Table:

Users : {
user_ykdF5b234afdgd : {
....

I want to display and sum the "punkte" in the Scoring child in every Userchild.

```
"Scoring" : [ {
        "Name" : "Name1",
        "punkte" : "100"
      }, {
        "Name" : "Name2",
        "punkte" : "150"
      } ],
```

I want add 100 + 150 and will display the 250 in my Android Layout.

```
      mDatabase.child("Users").child("user_ykdF5b234afdgd/Scoringboard").orderByChild("Name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot :
                            dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("debuug", String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Name").getValue()) + " "+ String.valueOf(snapshot.child("punkte").getValue()));

                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            Log.d("debuug", "Eingabe nicht valide");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
```

I tested this and get the scores, but this has two "fails"

1) How can i use this with all my child entries?

```
mDatabase.child("Users").child("user_ykdF5b234afdgd/Scoringboard").orderByChild("Name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

works only in these child.... TEILNEHMERDATA contains all my users

2) How can I sum the score?

Thanks =)

If anything is unclear, I will explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i suggest you adding the values of `punkte` as `Integers` and not as Strings. Then, i suggest you change your database structure a little bit. Your database structure should look like this:

```
Scoring
   |
   --- scoreId
   |     |
   |     --- Name: "Name1"
   |     |
   |     --- punkte: 100
   |
   --- scoreId
         |
         --- Name: "Name2"
         |
         --- punkte: 150
```

To achieve this, i suggest you using the `push()` method for creating the score ids. Assuming that `Users` is a direct child of your Firebase root, to sum those values please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int totalPunkte = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dSnapshot.child("Scoring").getChildren()) {
                int punkte = ds.child("punkte").getValue(Integer.class);
                totalPunkte = totalPunkte + punkte;
            }
        }
        Log.d("TAG", totalPunkte);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Changed it a little and it works: (see my own answer)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply.

Changed it a little and it works:

```
@Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot snapScore : snapshot.child("Scoringboard").getChildren()) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(snapScore.child("punkte").getValue()));
            }
            try {
                this.u = new User(snapshot.getKey(), ((String) snapshot.child("teamname").getValue()), sum);
                teilnehmerList.add(this.u);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.d("debug", "Punkte nicht valide");
            }
        }
    }
```

The Solution is:

```
int sum = 0;
for (DataSnapshot snapScore : snapshot.child("Scoringboard").getChildren()) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(snapScore.child("punkte").getValue()));
}
```